# Printing out ArrayList with toString

Tags: java, string, arraylist, tostring

When I create an ArrayList object and add other objects to it, printing out the ArrayList object will print out the memory references of the objects inside. However, if I add String to the ArrayList object, it will not print out the memory references of the String but rather the actual String value. String is also an object of a class right, so why does it not print out the String memory reference?

Comment: `String` overrides `Object.toString`. The other objects do not

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. That's a good, concise answer =p

Comment: Many other classes in addition to `String` implement `toString()` method, as your own classes can. And number which what you see calling "native" `Object#toString()` - is not memory reference of object, but its hash code.

Comment: [`String#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString--)

Answer (score 3):

The `toString` method for a `Collection` in Java (which is what an `ArrayList` extends) uses `String.valueOf` on each of its elements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()

> The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by `String.valueOf(Object)`.

`String.valueOf` is simply grabbing the `toString` value of the object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)

> if the argument is `null`, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of `obj.toString()` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

When you print a List, the List's `toString()` method is called, which in turn calls to `toString()` method of its elements.

The Object, which every class extends, class has a `toString()` method that creates the "memory address" output you're seeing (actually it's not the memory address, but anyway). The `String` class overrides the `toString()` method to return its contents.

To fix the output "problem", override the `toString()` method in you classes of the other objects you're adding to your List to return something "human readable".

Answer (score 0):

toString() method of Object class is overridden by Class AbstractCollection. ArrayList extends AbstractList and AbstractList extends AbstractCollection. Method detail is mentioned below.

public String toString()
Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

Overrides:
toString in class Object

Returns:
a string representation of this collection